# Determining if an image is closed after including in a ReportLab

Tags: python, windows, file-io, reportlab

I have written a Python script that will generate a series of graphs and then generate a PDF report that contains the graphs. The intention is that this will be generated on a server. I am using ReportLab to generate the PDF. The script is being run on a machine that is running Windows 7.

At the beginning of the script a list to store the ReportLab flowables and a list to store path of each figure is set.

```
Story = []
FigList = []
```

Each graph is generated using Matplotlib and saved as a PNG. The image is appended to Story and the path of the file is added to FigList.

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y)
fname = "figure.png"
fig.savefig(fname)
FigList.append(fname)
Story.append(Image(fname))
```

This is repeated for a number of images (approximately 10 - 15 in total). At the end of the script the document is built

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("report.pdf",
                        pagesize=A4,
                        rightMargin=cm,
                        leftMargin=cm,
                        topMargin=cm,
                        bottomMargin=cm)

doc.build(Story)
```

After this I wish to remove all the PNG files that have been created using

```
for f in FigList:
    if os.path.exists(f): os.remove(f)
```

However, I am presented with the following error

> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'image.png'

I am assuming here that the document creation process is being performed in a separate thread and so when the script attempts to remove the figure files they are still marked as open by the file manager.

It is important that these image files are deleted before the process finishes as this process may be executed many times, therefore the temporary image files will soon take up too much space.

Is there a way I can get the script to wait for all the images to be closed before proceeding to delete the files?

Comment: What's wrong with doc.close() before deleting?

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/backend_pdf_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages) instead of ReportLab?

Comment: @fp: There is no .close() instance for SimpleDocTemplate.

Comment: @jadkik94: Ideally I would produce each figure as an A4 page and then group them together, but in my case some plots contain a large number of lines and dots which prove a problem both rendering on screen and when sent to a printer!

Comment: @medgoode: I edited my answer, I think you can get a handle on the file objects. Take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that the problem can be solved by assigning `Image(...)` to a variable before appending it to `Story` and then deleting it afterwards. If we consider the example in the question, this modification becomes

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y)
fname = "figure.png"
fig.savefig(fname)
FigList.append(fname)
img = Image(fname)
Story.append(img)
del img
```

Note: This is not related to the file object created by `savefig()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your file open in a `with` statement? Usually python closes the file for you after leaving the `with` clause.

Edit: It looks like your `fig.savefig(fname)` might return the image file object. If that's correct, you could try calling close on each file object it returns after you're done.

Comment: He does not do that, he does not open the file. Reportlab does (or should do?) this for him!

Comment: If by a 'file open' you mean the call to SimpleDocTemplate then I have just tried
`with SimpleDocTemplate(...) as doc:`
but I get the error
`AttributeError: SimpleDocTemplate instance has no attribute '__exit__'`.
Each time a figure to the Story list (which I forgot to mention) is done as
`Figure("figure.png")`
and so I cannot wrap a `with` around this unfortunately.

Comment: I'm looking back at your question now, and it looks like you create the files; not `SimpleDocTemplate`. Or at least the .png files, right?

Comment: @notbad.jpeg: I am creating the PNG files and then passing the path of the file to `SimpleDocTemplate`. In each case I use `plt.close(fig)` to ensure I don't create too many figures in one go and (hopefully) minimise memory usage.

Comment: Many thanks for all your assistance with this question. After trial and error, based on some of your suggestions, I arrived at a solution!